# Хранение файла. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Пишу приложение на React. Нужно как-то глобально хранить файл из инпута. В `redux` записать файл невозможно. Использовать `localstorage` нельзя.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример как можно получить и хранить содержимое файла

```js
function save (){
  const file = document.querySelector('input').files[0]; 
  const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const content = reader.result; // <--- файл сохранен в переменную
      console.log(content);
    } 
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};
```

```html
<input type="file">
<button id="btn" onclick="save()" />save</button>
```